# How do I install jhat?

Tags: java, jmap, jhat

I have downloaded Java JDK 17 and I need to analyse a dump I did with the jmap command.

I have searched about how to do it and jhat is apparently an already installed command that lets you analyse the dumps from jmap but when I run the jhat command it says:

'jhat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

So I searched how to download it but I had no success and I tried to download it on my own with Chocolatey but with no results so does anyone have an idea about what to do to get jhat please?

Comment: By downgrading from Java JDK 17 to Java JDK 8. Because [jhat was removed in Java 9](https://openjdk.org/jeps/241).

Comment: I see... is there then an alternative to jhat that I can use with JDK 17? And without needing to be subscribed or have a licence or anything like that like with jprofiler?

Comment: It’s been [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/migrate/removed-tools-and-components.html#GUID-B49A964D-A2EF-4DAF-8A71-A64EF3E77C00).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) for profiling or [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) for heap analysis. There may be some similar functionality within those tools, depending on your specific needs.